# A webkit to make html/css of a website

Tags: html, css, webkit

I remember that sometime ago there was a project of a webkit designed to, for example, if you want to put some images of you website then you can choose the options and the webkit and then just copy the html/css code and it's functional on your site, modifying with php and that's all. You don't have to know css at all, it was great. But i miss the link and I don't have any idea what's the name of the website. 
It doesn't work only for images but also menus, links...etc. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you're using "webkit" properly here.

Comment: The `webkit` tag that you use here refers to the rendering engine of chrome, safari etc. Are you sure that is what you are referring to?

Comment: are you talking about some html/css framework or something.. Like bootstrap, HTML5 Boilerplate etc??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about an SDK like Dreamweaver.